# How to set font size for items in Xamarin Picker?

Tags: android, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I try to change the items font size in Xamarin.Picker for my Android app. In my project, I use `BindablePicker` that inherits from Picker class. Source [here](https://github.com/joacar/BindablePicker).

[image]

I spent some time to do research and I found that I should create a `PickerRenderer` class and render the Picker.

My renderer class:

```
public class BindablePickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var picker = e.NewElement;
        BindablePicker bp = (BindablePicker)this.Element;

        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            var pickerStyle = new Style(typeof(BindablePicker))
            {

                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter { Property = VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.Red }

                }
            };
            picker.Style = pickerStyle;
        }
    }
}
```

For test purposes I set the backgroundColor for `Picker` and it works fine. However, in my `PickerRenderer` class I only have access to `Control` property which is type of `Android.Widget.EditText`.

The effect :

[image]

***Question***

How can I access to `Picker` items, and set the font size for them? Is this possible?

Here is my repository with an example project.

https://github.com/k8mil/PickerRendererXamarin

***Related links***

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/

[Changing the default text color of a Picker control in Xamarin Forms for Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162207/changing-the-default-text-color-of-a-picker-control-in-xamarin-forms-for-windows)

[Font size in Picker control in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328630/font-size-in-picker-control-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I don't think this is possible for a generic picker.

You would likely have an easier time just rolling your own picker control in Forms code using a clickable label that pops up a list to select from.

I was able to style a date or time picker using styles in the Android styles.xml file, but since Android does not have a built in generic picker widget, I imagine that Forms is rolling it's own picker list as I can't find the dialog widget to theme that changes your list text size.

For a DatePicker, I can just add the following to the main style element in styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
```

and then add a new style element in style.xml

```
<style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textSize">60sp</item>
</style>
```

The above does change the text size for a DatePicker (no custom renderer required). Also the customer picker renderer is a bit of a misnomer... it really is just rendering the edit text field that shows the picked item, and allows opening the picker list on click.

I know this is not a solution, but just an indication as to what I found when checking this out and a suggestion that it is likely easiest to not use the Forms Picker type if you want such customization.

Answer (score 2):

I has been able to resolve this by add the line:

```
Control.TextSize = 30;
```

On `OnElementChanged` method:

```
public class BindablePickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control != null)
        {
            Control.TextSize = 30;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this can help someone that is looking for change font size of a Bindable picker.

Comment: This will change the font size of selected value label. I want to change to font size of Picker items, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv28w.png)